# Math.radians inside Math.sin

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Hy,

I write a script for calculating delta e 2000, how to figure this to work on google spreadsheet:

```
var DH = 2 * (Math.pow((var1 * var2), 0.5)) * (Math.sin((Math.radians(var3))/2));
```

or this, same error

```
360 + (Math.degrees(Math.atan2(var1, var2)));
```

I got this error:
TypeError: Cannot find function radians in object [object Math]. (line 232, file "Code")

Comment: use uppercase : RADIANS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Math object do not have the method `radians()`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math

> To convert radians to degrees, divide by (Math.PI / 180), and multiply
>   by this to convert the other way.

Comment: In this place I found the radians method...
https://support.google.com/docs/table/25273?hl=en

Comment: The link your are referencing is a list of the cell formulas that can be used in the spreadsheet. These are not found in the JavaScript Math object.

Comment: the same case in "360 + (Math.degrees(Math.atan2(var1, var2)));" ?

Comment: yes, only the method listed in the link in my answer will work. These are the only methods the Math object has.

Comment: I corrected this: var DH = 2 * (Math.pow((Cinds * Cind), 0.5)) * (Math.sin(((Math.PI / 180)*Dh)/2)); but I dont have any ideea how to figure this: 360 + (Math.degrees(Math.atan2(var1, var2)));

Comment: Assuming `var1` and `var2` is in radians you should do something like: `var RAD_PER_DEG = Math.PI/180;
var value = 360 +  Math.atan2(var1, var2)/RAD_PER_DEG;`